# Adding b64 images support to the default whitelist of HTML Purifier

Tags: php, html, htmlpurifier

How can i add b64 images support to the default whitelist ?

adding b64 images support like this:

```
$config->set('URI.AllowedSchemes', array('data' => true));
```

works, but it also resets the entire default whitelist.

So, my question is: is there any way of adding `'URI.AllowedSchemes', array('data' => true)` to the default whitelist ? Somehow using `->addAttribute()` ?

Comment: Is a base 64 image not just a string?

Comment: yes it is Thomas